# How do you close a window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, client-side

I have a zend framework project and I am loading some javascript in a page. How do I close that page from inside the javascript code?

window.close() only works when the current window/tab/page was opened with window.open(), that not being my case, it's not a solution.

Any other solution?

Comment: Zend has nothing to do with this, since is is a server-side framework and this is happening on the client.

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned that just to make sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are ways to do this, but they are "hack"ish.

javaScript can not, for security reasons, close a window that it did not open. You can, however, use a trick to make the browser think your current window was opened by javaScript:

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
```

Comment: wow, I just tested this out and I can't believe it actually works! can't figure out how to make it re-size and move the window unfortunately, that requires additional user interaction.

Comment: I never got to test this. I ended up redirecting to a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no other solution

> Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script

See more info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close)

Comment: this is mostly incorrect. jbabey's answer actually works in the latest Chrome, IE, Opera, and Safari, but not in FF.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**open("/", '_self').close();**